# sbt not picking up dependencies with a crossProject

Tags: sbt, sbt-crossproject

SBT is not picking up changes to my source code and recompiling appropriately.

I'm working on a multi-project build with two projects:

- cli: a command-line interface for using the library.  It's the root project.
- lib: code that is used by the `cli` and that I want to publish separately.  It's cross-platform, both JVM and JS. The `cli` is JVM only.

The `build.sbt` file for my minimal example is:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.3.1"

lazy val lib = crossProject(JSPlatform, JVMPlatform)
  .crossType(CrossType.Full)
  .in(file("lib"))
  .jsSettings(scalacOptions ++= Seq("-scalajs"))

lazy val cli = (project in file("."))
  .dependsOn(lib.jvm)
  .aggregate(lib.jvm, lib.js)
```

The "library", in `lib/shared/src/main/scala/mylib/MyLib.scala` is

```
package mylib

object MyLib {
  val life = 42 + 0
}
```

and my "command line interpreter" in `src/main/scala/myapp/Main.scala` is

```
package myapp

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(mylib.MyLib.life)
  }
}
```

Running this program from within SBT produces `42`, of course.

However, I edit the definition of `life` to be `life = 42 + 1`, rerun the program, it still prints `42`.

In the following test, I changed `MyLib.scala` at 16:02.  I then waited until 16:05 and re-ran the program.  Note that the `MyLib` class files in the `lib/jvm/target` directory were updated.  The class files in `./target` were not.  I don't think I expect the class files for `Main` to be updated, but not updating the class files for `MyLib` smells fishy to me.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 bwbecker  staff   695  7 Mar 16:05 ./lib/jvm/target/scala-3.3.1/classes/mylib/MyLib$.class
-rw-r--r--  1 bwbecker  staff   280  7 Mar 16:05 ./lib/jvm/target/scala-3.3.1/classes/mylib/MyLib.class
-rw-r--r--  1 bwbecker  staff    52  7 Mar 16:02 ./lib/shared/src/main/scala/mylib/MyLib.scala
-rw-r--r--  1 bwbecker  staff   107  7 Mar 15:19 ./src/main/scala/myapp/Main.scala
-rw-r--r--  1 bwbecker  staff  1002  7 Mar 15:52 ./target/scala-3.3.1/classes/myapp/Main$.class
-rw-r--r--  1 bwbecker  staff   296  7 Mar 15:52 ./target/scala-3.3.1/classes/myapp/Main.class
-rw-r--r--  1 bwbecker  staff   695  7 Mar 15:59 ./target/scala-3.3.1/classes/mylib/MyLib$.class
-rw-r--r--  1 bwbecker  staff   280  7 Mar 15:59 ./target/scala-3.3.1/classes/mylib/MyLib.class
```

This was done with just sbt and vi.  No fancy IDE running that might be interfering with things.

I figure I've made a mistake in `build.sbt`.  I've read the [SBT documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html#Aggregation) and this excellent [StackOverflow article](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html#Aggregation) on `.dependsOn` and `.aggregate`.  But I don't see the problem -- except that I'm involving a crossProject.

Thanks for any assistance you can offer.

---

I first noted this issue with SBT v1.9.7.  Updated to the most recent (1.9.9) with no change.  MacOS 14.2.1.  openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17

Comment: What SBT commands are you running?

Comment: Really simple:  "run"

Comment: I don't know if it's something standard TBH but I believe you have to use `sbt ~run` to get hot reloading. Not sure if related or not to your issue though.

Comment: No, this is not a hot reloading issue.  The more complete sequence is:
(1) sbt> run
(2) edit the code in MyLib
(3) sbt> run

I expect the last run to pick up the change I made but it does not.

Comment: You may open a discussion/issue on sbt's GitHub. It's not clear to me if this an expected behaviour or not TBH.